# How can I add Axis Title to axes in R maps?

Tags: r, rmaps

I am trying to add Lat and Lon axis titles to a map in **R** maps.

I cannot find the appropriate arguments in **R** maps.

```
library(rMaps)
    chile <- map("worldHires", regions="Chile", plot=FALSE, fill=TRUE)
    map("worldHires", xlim = c(-90,-50), ylim = c(-60,-10))
    map(chile, col="grey", fill=TRUE, add=TRUE)
    map.axes()
    map.scale(metric = TRUE, ratio = FALSE, cex = 0.7)
```

I want to add Latitude and Longitude as axis titles.

Answer (score 1):

Was it that what you were looking for?

```
mtext(c("Longitude", "Latitude"), side=c(1,2), line = 2.5)
```